# Click event on owl-item not triggered in owl carousel 1.3.3 when navigation is true

Tags: javascript, carousel, owl-carousel

Anyone help me on owl-carousel.
Click event on item not triggered in owl carousel v1.3.3 while navigation is on.
My code is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
          items: 3,
          mouseDraggable: false,
          navigation: true,
          scrollPerPage: true,
          rewindNav: false,
          pagination: false,
          navigationText: ['<span>&#60;</span>', '<span>&#62;</span>'],
        })
        $('.owl-carousel').on('click', '.owl-item>div', function () {
          alert('click');
        })
      })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var owl = $('.owl-carousel');
  owl.owlCarousel({
    margin: 10,
    navigation: true,
    loop: true,
  })
  $('.owl-carousel').on('click', '.owl-item>div', function () {
          alert('click');
  })
})
```

```css
.owl-carousel .item {
    height: 10rem;
    background: #4DC7A0;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>



<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item">
    <h4>1</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>2</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>3</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>4</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>5</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>6</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>7</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>8</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>9</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>10</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>11</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4>12</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

<s>There is a good chance that owl carousel stops the propagation of events from the parent element (`'.owl-carousel'`).</s>

<s>So rather than adding the click event on `'.owl-carousel'` and reaching its child, add it on the child `'.owl-item>div'` directly.</s>

**Update:**
Try this, make sure to set your event listener after the document is loaded. This gives a good enough time for your HTML to render.

Comment: First of all thanks for the reply.
But the answer you suggested not working.
But when I disable the navigation it's working fine. The issue is replicated only if navigation is true.

Comment: @SachinDongare, I think your DOM may not be ready when you are adding your event listeners, thats why you must be facing this issue. Try enclosing your code within a $(document).ready() method.